# Sugar at the bottom still

Tags: bottle-conditioning, sugar

I've made a lager which is now all bottled. I put half a teaspoon of brewing sugar in to the bottle once the lager was in the bottles.

When I looked at the lager the day after I noticed that there is a bit of sugar at the bottom of the glass what did I do wrong.
I Am a newbie to home brew.

Comment: Did you prime the bottles with regular white sugar? How much did you use? did the suggar go straight in the bottle?

Comment: Put half a teaspoon in to the bottle with brewing sugar.did this when the lager was in the bottles.

Comment: I'm guessing that the larger was done fermenting before you bottled. But are you certain you see sugar not just yeast falling to the bottom? Have seen people priming this way shake the bottles after capping, did you do that?

Comment: Is it a Lager concentrate kit?  What was the yeast ?  How big are your bottles?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the sugar directly to your bottles, you need to shake them well after capping to mix the sugar and the yeast.  You can even shake them for the first few days.

To acheive bottle fermentation, make sure to check :

1. **The temperature**: make sure it is hot enough for the yeast to be active. Check the yeast package for the ideal temperature and try to get close to it.
2. **Allow some time**: bottle conditionning can a a few days, you can shake your bottles the first few days. Do not refrigerate before one week.
3. **Yeast:**  if you filter your beer, you might not have enough yeast left.  Avoid filtering if you bottle-condition.
4. **Sugar:** have enough sugar.  Half a tea spoon per bottle seems ok if you have standard 341ml bottles.  For a 1L bottle it would not be sufficient.  Some people would add the sugar first then the beer. For me I find that adding the sugar to the whole batch (after racking) is more practicle but all methods normally work.
5. **Do not overfill**: Leave at least an inch of air.  Yeast works better if some air is present, and it will allow the CO2 to take its place.

After a week, I would try to open one bottle.  Check if the beer is carbonated, and also if the residue is sugar or yeast.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be yeast.  Given enough time if it is sugar it will dissolve on its own.  I'd just be patient, give the bottles two weeks at room temperature.  Then chill one down and open it up to test for carbonation.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the yeast byproduct? Best way I've been able to tell what is on the bottom is by opening one up after a week or two. Make sure it's carbonated. Taste test (drink and enjoy). Lastly, make sure that the last drink is what you think it is - sugar.

If it is all sugar and not the yeast byproduct, try shaking them all up and turning them upside down, in a case (for support), for a day or two then do it again leaving it upright. There shouldn't be a lot of oxygen in the bottle. So there won't be any concern over oxygenating. The technique I described is essentially increasing the surface area for contact between yeast and sugar.

There are a lot of reasons why the yeast might not have taken hold in your brew... Pitching too hot. Didn't give the yeast enough time at optimal temp for pre-pitching multiplying. The yeast may not have received their initial gulp of air or provided enough trace nutrients before going down to ferment. Etc.

Additionally, with lager yeasts you will want to pitch cooler. Pitch a lager yeast when below 70 degrees F. Cool very slowly (days), let the yeast open up. Too fast can cause the yeast to stay dormant (don't just stick in a refrigerator), but also know that lager yeasts are slower fermenters and optimally grow when in the range of 40-60 degrees F depending on the strain. It's good brewing form to know your yeast before dumping it in the primary.

Here are some good reads:

http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-01/beersci-what-difference-between-lager-and-ale

https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/101/yeast/

Good luck and Cheers!